# Set cookies login with curl on php

Tags: php, curl, cookies

I want to scrap some data, but I need to log in. So, my idea is to copy the cookies when I log in to my program. But I don't know why, but if I'm using my program, I kept redirect to login pages. I already compared it, but the cookies are same.

Here's the header if I login using my google chrome, (Copied it from request header):

`GET /example/data/data.jsp?date=01-Jan-2001&_=1439020103330 HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.130 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,ms;q=0.6
Cookie: SESSIONID=BA4BA42C628D5C6EB959D49DB745D94A.NGXA; __utma=77920972.1013585791.1438786361.1438966138.1439020034.5; __utmc=77920972; __utmz=77920972.1438786423.2.2.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not%20provided)`

My curl code:

```
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
            $f = fopen('request.txt', 'w');
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR , $f);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch',
'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,ms;q=0.6',
'Cookie: SESSIONID=BA4BA42C628D5C6EB959D49DB745D94A.NGXA; __utma=77920972.1013585791.1438786361.1438966138.1439020034.5; __utmc=77920972; __utmz=77920972.1438786423.2.2.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not%20provided)',
'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1',
'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.130 Safari/537.36',
'X-DevTools-Emulate-Network-Conditions-Client-Id: 3A45EE97-D41F-45A3-AFCD-1540014377A7
'));
```

Here's my request.txt used to debug my program header:

```
    * About to connect() to www.example.com port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 202.43.163.203... * connected
* Connected to www.example.com (202.43.163.203) port 80 (#0)
> GET /example/data/data.jsp?date=01-Jan-2001&_=1439020103330 HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
Accept: */*

Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,ms;q=0.6
Cookie: SESSIONID=BA4BA42C628D5C6EB959D49DB745D94A.NGXA; __utma=77920972.1013585791.1438786361.1438966138.1439020034.5; __utmc=77920972; __utmz=77920972.1438786423.2.2.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not%20provided)
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.130 Safari/537.36
X-DevTools-Emulate-Network-Conditions-Client-Id: 3A45EE97-D41F-45A3-AFCD-1540014377A7


< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Date: Sat, 08 Aug 2015 09:44:06 GMT
< Server: Apache
< Set-Cookie: SESSIONID=7C8779894A3CE29D4BCED4B4D311E07E.NGXA; Path=/example/; HttpOnly
< Location: http://www.example.com/login.jsp
< Content-Length: 0
< Content-Type: text/plain
< 
* Connection #0 to host www.example.com left intact
* Closing connection #0
```

This my first time scrapping data with login user, but did I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cookies can be set via the `CURLOPT_COOKIE`. In your case

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'SESSIONID=BA4BA42C628D5C6EB959D49DB745D94A.NGXA');
```

With semicolon space you can add more cookies to the request. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php for more information.

If you want to store and re-use the cookies you can also use `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` and `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR`.

Comment: hai, thanks for the reply. but it still redirect to login pages. do you have another idea?

Comment: Never mind, you are right, I accidentally add cookies in front of 'SESSIONID', that's why it wasn't working. Thx so much.